# Adjusting a Vlookup according to a combo box value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a system which inputs a code to a cell on a spreadsheet. It does this by using a Vlookup to determine which date it is. If you look at the code below the nput is what does this Vlookup.

What I want it to do is move down a cell per amount the amount that will be in a combo box value called DayAmount. What would I need to enter for it to look at the next cell?

For example if the 5th of January is in A24 I want it to also enter the same code in the 6th and 7th of January which the Vlookup knows is A25 and A26.

```
Private Sub Submitplan_Click()

' This searches for the selected engineer
        Dim EngineerFound As Range
        Dim Front As Worksheet
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim area As Worksheet
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim tabchange As String
        Set Front = wb.Worksheets("Front")

               x = Front.Cells(Front.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

                With Front.Range("F8:F" & x)
                    Set EngineerFound = .Find(Engbox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                End With

                EngRow = EngineerFound.Row

'This is the section which enters the data into the right date
    tabchange = ("Area") & Front.Range("B8")
    Set area = wb.Worksheets(tabchange)
    y = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(CDate(Datebox.Value)), area.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
    nPut = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Key, area.Range("A:B"), 2, 0) & 
Hoursbox.Value

    z = area.Range("C:C").Find(Engbox.Value).Row
    If area.Cells(z, y).Value = " B/H" Then
        area.Cells(z, y).Value = nPut & " " & "B/H"
    ElseIf area.Cells(z, y).Value = " WK" Then
        area.Cells(z, y).Value = nPut & " " & "WK"
    Else: area.Cells(z, y).Value = nPut
    End If
   ' If DayAmount <> "" Then

    'End If
    Call Update
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Please ensure you're using Option Explicit.  Cannot find the actual use of nPut in the given code, just what it is filled with.  Will be useful when trying to give simple responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you have a value in a combobox (will say *DayAmount*) which will be assigned until a that value is met.

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long, k as Long
i = ActiveCell.Row
j = DayAmount
k = 1
If j > 1 Then
    Do until k = j-1
        Cells(k+1,1).Value = Cells(i,1)>Value
        k = i + k
    Loop
End If
```

Or you could use a filldown, or .value match, and when you enter the line to the destination cell, you use:

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long
i = ActiveCell.Row
j = DayAmount
Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i+j,1)).Value = "" 'input here
```

Note the arbitrary activecell and column 1 usage as i'm unsure exactly where this would be for you.

Regarding, specifically, the use of nPut, you can use offset to help, such as:

```
Range(nPut, nPut.Offset(DayAmount,0)) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Key, area.Range("A:B"), 2, 0) & Hoursbox.Value
```

Note that I haven't tested the latter and it's off the top of my head.